# can't using lambda to filter list item through it's index

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
```

Hi, I'm trying to learn about lambda in python and I'm wondering if I want to filter onto just the 'Python' list item, why can't i just use

```
print filter(lambda x: x[2], languages)
```

which still returns the entire list, and have to use

```
print filter(lambda x: x == 'Python', languages)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are applying filter function, you have to give a condition which when satisfied returns the value.

```
print filter(lambda x: x[2], languages)
```

In first filter, x[2] will be true in each case as X gets values HTML so, x[2] will be M and so on. That's why it is giving all values.

While in second case,you have given the condition **x == 'Python'** so it will give you the proper result.

Comment: After reading your reply, I realized my problem is not understanding the condition of filter() rather than lambda. Thank you for helping me in the right direction! I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

#### Imagine the `filter` as a `for` loop.

`print filter(lambda x: x[2], languages)` is equivalent to

```
result = []
for x in languages:
    if x[2]:
        result.append(x)
print result
```

Notice that instead of calling `languages[2]`, which is `Python`, this calls `x[2]`, which evaluates as `if 'M':` for `'HTML'`, `if 'v'` for `'Javascript'`, and so on—since these strings are all non-empty, they are evaluated as `True`, and thus added to `result`.

Instead, `print filter(lambda x: x == 'Python', languages)` is equivalent to

```
result = []
for x in languages:
    if x == 'Python':
        result.append(x)
print result
```

Which loops over `languages`, appending items that match `'Python'`, which is the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out 'Python' use `!=` (not equals) operator as follows.

```
print filter(lambda x: x != 'Python', languages)
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use list comprehensions for it?

```
languages = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]

languages=[ lang for lang in languages if lang=='Python']

print languages

output would be 
['Python']
```

It's more cleaner and faster than filter , given you are using lambda with it,  [for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)